# VB.net Count Rows in Access Database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to count the enteries of my database where the users are 'employees'.
I have an Access DB with cName, cAge, cStatus

cStatus can either be 'Employee' or 'Customer'.

I have no Idea how to get the Number of my 'Employees'.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a simple query. Since you didn't include details like table name or database name, I can only guess them:

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection = Nothing
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
Dim numberOfEmployees as Int = 0;
con = New OleDbConnection()
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=pathToDatabase"
con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) From tableToQuery where cStatus = \"Employee\"", con)
numberOfEmployees = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```